# Method not Allowed HTTP Exception

Tags: laravel, store

Here is the code of HTML Form

```
<form method="POST" action={{ route('store') }} class="col s12">
        @csrf
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input name="task" id="task" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="task">New Task</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        @include('partials.coworkers')
        <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Add Task</button>
      </form>
      @isWorker
      <br><br><br>
      <form action="" class="col s6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <select>
              <option value="" disabled selected>Send Invitation To</option>
              <option value="1">Option 1</option>
              <option value="2">Option 2</option>
              <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
            <label>Send Invitation</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Send Invitation</a>
      </form>
```

Here is my code for store method inside a controller.

```
public function store(Request $request){
        if ($request->input('task')) {
            $task = new Task;
            $task->content = $request->input('task');
            Auth::user()->tasks()->save($task);
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

web.php:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', 'CrudApp@index');
    Route::get('/store', 'CrudApp@store')->name('store');
    Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'CrudApp@edit')->name('edit');
    Route::get('/update/{id}', 'CrudApp@update')->name('update');
    Route::get('/delete/id', 'CrudApp@delete')->name('delete');
});
```

I want to store the task into database. as soon as I hit save `MethodNotAllowedHTTPException` occurs and i am unable to figure out how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

make it after any changes in route file (web.php in your case).

And now your code. Look u use POST:

```
<form method="POST" action={{ route('store') }} class="col s12">
```

so change:

```
Route::get('/store', 'CrudApp@store')->name('store');
```

on:

```
Route::post('/store', 'CrudApp@store')->name('store');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below command you will get the List of Routes where you can find your route:

`php artisan route:list`

Then as @Adam answer :

`php artisan route:clear`

`php artisan route:cache`

And in your query I think you are using Resource Controller.

If you are using resource method then you dont have to write all route separately

You can write your route in one line also:

`Route::resource('demo-segment', 'DemoController');`

You can also skip the unneccessory method from your resource controller

```
Route::resource('demo-segment', 'DemoController', [
    'except' => ['show', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy']  // This is not usable methods
]);
```

Thanks, might help someone.